# Parameter is not valid exception while converting Stream to Image

Tags: c#, database, image, stream

I am working on the Northwind.sdf database and I am trying to save the photo of an Employee from the Employees table by the below code:
I got the byte[]. row is a DataRow from DataTable.

```
byte[] b = (byte[])row["Photo"];
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(b);

Image im = Image.FromStream(str);
im.Save("Fuller.png");
```

I am getting Parameter is not valid exception while trying to convert the stream to image.

Comment: Image.FromStream(str)....

Comment: Simply googling it and I got these: http://google.com/search?q=Parameter+is+not+valid+exception the most possible reason is your byte array doesn't contain valid image data.

Comment: Thanks Ken, I too googled it... Is that any decoding or something we need to do it when retrieving photo from Northwind database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these articles: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_load_blob.html and http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050911.asp
"Northwind Employees table were designed from MS Access, which expects a 78 byte OLE header". You have to omit the first 78 from the MemoryStream.

```
MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(); 
int offset = 78;              
str.Write(b, offset, b.Length - offset);
Image im = Image.FromStream(str);
```